# how to force the a Jquery function to fire only one time for the selector

Tags: jquery

i have defined the following script to enable the "submit" button once the user start typing in any input field text field:-

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
    $("input[type= 'text']").change(function () {

        var $this = $("input[type='submit']");
        $this.prop('disabled', false);
    });
</script>
```

but can i force the above script to fire only once ,, since it will be waste of processing to enable the submit button each time the user type in a text field,, where the submit button will be already enabled after the first `.change`.
BR

Answer (score 3):

```
$("input[type='text']").one('change', function () { // fires only one time
        var $this = $("input[type='submit']");
        $this.prop('disabled', false);
        $("input[type='text']").off('change');
    })
```

Answer (score 3):

`$('<selector>').change(...)` will bind the event handler to each element, so simply using [`.one` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](http://api.jquery.com/one/) won't help you here. It will still execute once for each element, although you want to execute it only once, disregarding which element it was triggered by.

You can `unbind` (or `off`) the event handler from each element after it was executed once:

```
var $elements = $("input[type= 'text']");
$("input[type= 'text']").change(function() {
    //...
    $elements.unbind('change');
});
```

This can easily be turned into a plugin (simple version, the signature of the original `.one()` method is a bit more complex):

```
$.fn.one_all = function(event, handler) {
    var $elements = this;
    $elements.on(event, function() {
        $elements.off(event, handler);
        handler.apply(this, arguments);
    });
};
```